# location of Firefox extensions in Mac OS?

Tags: firefox

In Mac OS X, where are installed extensions for Firefox located?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/[profile name]/extensions

Comment: Thanks man! I got stuck by the red herring folder of ~/Library/Mozilla

Answer (score -3):

In my computer (MacOS X 10.7.5, Firefox 16.0.2), they are installed in :

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins
```

Here is a list of files inside this directory :

```
AdobePDFViewer.plugin
DivXBrowserPlugin.plugin
Flash Player.plugin
Flip4Mac WMV Plugin.plugin
GarminGpsControl.plugin
JavaAppletPlugin.plugin -> //System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin
Quartz Composer.webplugin
QuickTime Plugin.plugin
Scorch.plugin
Silverlight.plugin
flashplayer.xpt
googletalkbrowserplugin.plugin
iPhotoPhotocast.plugin
npdivx.xpt
npgtpo3dautoplugin.plugin
nsIQTScriptablePlugin.xpt
```